# Increasing expiration time of google managed certificate used in fully managed Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

While going through the certificate used by cloud run, it has very short validity (90 days). We have a requirement where the caller has to import these cert to make a successful call on cloud run. Is there any way to increase the validity of certificates used by cloud run and completely managed by Google.

[image: Cloud run certificated]

Comment: Please update your question with details on this: **has to import these cert to make a successful call on cloud run**. Certificates are public and are signed by a trusted root. There is no need to import them and there is no requirement to know anything about the SSL certificate to call Cloud Run.

Answer (score 1):

***No longer valid, see John comment** -> Google manages the certificate with [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) that generates a 90 days' life SSL certificate. You can see more details [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#what-is-the-lifetime-for-let-s-encrypt-certificates-for-how-long-are-they-valid)*

If you need a longer life duration certificate, you can manage [the certificate by yourselves](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs). You also need to create a load balancer, on which you can load your certificate, and then put [Cloud Run as the backend of this load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless)

Comment: Google is now a CA (Google Trust Services). Those certificates have **GTS Root R[1-4]** as the root certificate: https://pki.goog/

Comment: @JohnHanley, good to know. So I haven't link for the explanation, except the similarity with Let's Encrypt!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Google Managed certificate they will indeed last for 90 days, but about one month before the expiry date, Google cloud starts the renewal process automatically, so you are not left without a certificate. So you do not need to worry about manually renewing  the certificates.

You can find more details on this [here](http://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs?hl=en#renewal)